# Create a sitemap of sites/site collections

Tags: 2013, site

I want to create a site map of all site collections and sub sites contained within (preferable with size in MB/GB).  Is there such a program?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to build a site map is by using PowerShell, Excel and Visio.

You can use this PowerShell script to create a Excel-sheet of all site collections and sub sites in a web application and then use it to build a diagram in Visio.

```
Get-SPWebApplication http://portal.contoso.com | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, URL, ID, ParentWebID | Export-CSV C:\sharepointinventory.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You can of course add properties in the script above. Use the below script to see what properties that are available from the SPWeb object.

```
Get-SPWebApplication http://portal.contoso.com | Get-SPSite -limit all | get-SPWeb -limit all | get-member -membertype property
```

You can then run another script to get the site collections size and then add the values in a new column in the Excel-sheet that were created from the previous script.

```
Get-SPwebapplication http://portal.contoso.com | Get-SPSite -limit all | select url, @{label="Size in MB";Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property "Size in MB" | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

[Using PowerShell to find site collection size in SharePoint 2010](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=270) (Still applicable in SP2013.)

Then follow the steps from this post how to import the sheet in Visio and create a roadmap over you environment.

[Build an inventory before a SharePoint Migration and put it in Visio](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/how-to-build-an-inventory-before-sharepoint-migration)